# Typescript compile options on visual studio 2015 rc

Tags: compilation, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Recently I Programmed in typescript with VS2015 Preview.
Now i have installed VS2015 RC and i cannot find the following options i used to see in Project Properties:

1. Compile on save.
2. Don't make .map files.
3. Module(requirejs/amd...)

I have tried to search in other properties pages without success.

Thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ran into a similar issue myself. Apparently there is no UI (yet) for setting this. I ended up editing the project file manually (in my case an .xproj file). 
By adding a `<PropertyGroup>` you can set TypeScript options.

For instance, the following allowed me to use CommonJS module generation:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>commonjs</TypeScriptModuleKind>
</PropertyGroup>
```

While searching for the other possible options you can use, I found this answer, which is basically the same as mine, but more elaborate:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353321/3131828

Hope this helps!