# How do I expose my TypeScript code to my JavaScript code via RequireJS/AMD?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

This is a legacy project so I'm not going to change everything to TypeScript, but I do want to slowly start combining it, so I want to call TypeScript code from normal JS, using RequireJS. I have a `1-login.js` and `realtimeConnection.ts` (that's transformed into `realtimeConnection.js`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/content/scripts/realtimeConnection.js" src="/content/require.min.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/pages/1-login.js"></script>
```

This is `1-login.js`:

```
(function ($) {
    requirejs(["/content/scripts/realtimeConnection.js"], function (rtCon) {
        debugger;
        // The probelm: rtCon === undefined
    });
    ...
    ...
}(jQuery));
```

`realtimeConnection.ts`:

```
export class RealtimeConnection {    
}
```

Which in turn becomes `realtimeConnection.js`:

```
"use strict";
var RealtimeConnection = (function () {
    function RealtimeConnection() {
    }
    return RealtimeConnection;
}());
exports.RealtimeConnection = RealtimeConnection;
```

So how do I expose my TS code to the JS code via RequireJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found it: I needed to tell the TypeScript compiler to build it in a RequireJS/AMD style:

Since I'm using Visual Studio 2015, I placed a `tsconfig.json` file with the appropriate settings (`"module": "amd"` in particular) in the root content dir, [as per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31859331/587467).

Now it works.

### Now to whoever going to mark it as duplicate:

[That allegedly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30352657/587467), which its answer I linked above, has the title "Visual Studio 2015 RC does not create sourcemap when saving Typescript file". The answer is the same, but the question is different.

I found my answer, hope it'll help others as well... [BTNOMB](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=BTNOMB).. just saying...